# Right way using setState with redux state conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a question about what is the best practice using setState with redux state in component

For example: I have a component with an `onClick` event.

In the component A's `onClick` event, I have dispatch some redux action which will change redux state from reducer:

```
someOnClickFunc = () => {
   this.props.someReduxAction()
}
```

and I have a component b:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

class ComponentB extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          someValue: false,
        };
      }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {someValue}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    someReduxState: state.someReduxState
  });

  export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
  )(ComponentB);
```

My component B received redux state and I want to change component self state with this redux state.

I can do it like that after render.

```
if (this.props.someReduxState.someVal == true) {
  this.state.someValue = true
}
```

But i don't want to use this.state... I prefer to use this.setState like that:

```
  if (this.props.someReduxState.someVal == true) {
      this.setState({
        someValue: true
      })
    }
```

where is the best place to do that.

When I do that after **render()** , or **componentDidUpdate** I'm getting this error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: You can do it in `componentDidUpdate` but you'll also need to check that the state's value is not the same as the props' value (wasn't already set). But why do this at all ?

Comment: My guess is you don't need this at all but not enough shown to know what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: i'm trying to do that because i need to change component b state from component a how to that in another way? if they are not parent child each other

Comment: and componentDidUpdate too give same error

Comment: This seems like an antipattern... Why can you not just use the state from your store? There's almost certainly a better way to do what you want to do.

Comment: Yes you right i don't need to use component based state if i will use the redux. There all need to be use from redux or just in component state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way here is to use the **`componentDidUpdate`** method. But there's a catch, you need to check if the new props from the redux state are equal to the already existing props. Only then, you should proceed to mutate your state. Here's an example:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if(prevProps.somedata.data !== this.props.somedata.data) {
              this.setState({                  //update the state after checking
                 someProperty: value
               }); 
     }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand how use this approach in my situation. nextProps.someData will be my redux state ?

Comment: Edited the answer. The lifecycle method accepts two parameters. prevProps and prevState. By using `mapStateToProps` you have the new props in `this.props`. You can compare the previous props with the new ones and decide whether to update or not.

Comment: By updating, I mean mutating the state using `this.setState`.

Comment: i use it like that: if (
      prevProps.someReduxState.someVal !== this.props.someReduxState.someVal
    )  it's right way? it's worked.

Comment: If it's working for you, please upvote the answer :) . I believe it's the right way, you should study up some more about lifecycle methods, how they work and react optimizations techniques.